How does Telegram Android app is able to show notification of incoming call without POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission when app in the foreground?
So if I disable notifications for Telegram app then it's not able to notify a user about incoming calls when app is in the background/killed.
But if I open the Telegram app then it's able to receive incomings call notifications, firstly I thought it was custom UI displayed in the activity but not, it's also displayed in the system notification panel of Android.
How can it be achieved for my own video/voice call app?
Is it something related to ConnectionService and TelecomManager to achieve that and show notification without post notifications permission?

They probably attach the notification to ForegroundService, which doesn't need the notification permission: "Apps don't need to request the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in order to launch a foreground service. " Source: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

@DerekK it's possible to start a foreground service without POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission but still the notification of the foreground service won't be visible without this permission :)


If your app configures itself to self-manage phone calls, you don't need the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in order for your app to send notifications that use the Notification.CallStyle notification style.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#exemptions-self-manage-phone-calls
See that link and the APIs it links to for how to configure an app that way.

ok, yeah, it makes sense, I was already trying to test ConnectionService before that, but something was wrong with PhoneAccount (disabled state), need more time to learn this stuff
